# Лучший способ для замены подстрок из одного массива на значения из другого массива?

Tags: ios, строки, swift

Есть строка (S1) вида: "Сб: 16:00-18:00, Пн: 13:00, Сб-Вс: 16:00"

и есть два массива подстрок:

(A1) - ["Пн", "Вт", "Ср", "Чт", "Пт", "Сб", "Вс"] и (A2) - ["-1-",    "-2-", "-3-", "-4-", "-5-", "-6-", "-7-"]

Нужно в строке (S1) заменить все вхождения из массива (A1) на соответствующие значения из массива (A2)

Т.е в примере выше должно получиться: "-6-: 16:00-18:00, -1-: 13:00,
-6---7-: 16:00"

Какой лучший (эффективное выполнение и короткая запись) способ на Swift для подобного преобразования?

Первое, что приходит в голову:

```
let a1 = ["Пн", "Вт", "Ср", "Чт", "Пт", "Сб", "Вс"]
let a2 = ["-1-", "-2-", "-3-", "-4-", "-5-", "-6-", "-7-"]

var s = "Сб: 16:00-18:00, Пн: 13:00, Сб-Вс: 16:00"

for i in 0..<a1.count {
    s = s.replacingOccurrences(of: a1[i], with: a2[i])
}

print(s) // -6-: 16:00-18:00, -1-: 13:00, -6---7-: 16:00
```

но, возможно, есть более удачный вариант. И может даже он будет регистронезависимым.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас самое простое решение. Для регистронезависимого варианта используйте `caseInsensitive`:

```
var someString = "сб: 16:00-18:00, ПН: 13:00, Сб-Вс: 16:00"

let whatToReplace = ["Пн", "Вт", "Ср", "Чт", "Пт", "Сб", "Вс"]
let onWhichToReplace = ["-1-", "-2-", "-3-", "-4-", "-5-", "-6-", "-7-"]

assert(whatToReplace.count == onWhichToReplace.count)
for i in whatToReplace.indices {
    someString = someString.replacingOccurrences(of: whatToReplace[i], with: onWhichToReplace[i], options: .caseInsensitive)
}
print(someString)
```

Comment: спасибо за "options: .caseInsensitive" )

Comment: я думал, может есть какой-то метод который использует массивы для поиска/замены в качестве параметров (типа как в php http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-ireplace.php), но я его не увидел в документации ...